# how to sync ceph bucket with scaleway s3 bucket or any s3 bucket for?

Tags: ceph

i,m trying to sync a ceph cluster to a scaleway s3 bucket
i have the secret, access token and https endpoint for my s3 bucket
**ceph version: mimic**
i followed the cloud sync module guide at the following link below:
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/cloud-sync-module/
**what am i trying to achieve?

sync one of my ceph buckets to the s3 bucket**

here is what i know so far:

- the sync modules are based on multi-site which my cluster does already (i have 2 zones my zone group)
- i should add another zone of type cloud with my s3 bucket endpoints
- i should configure which bucket i want to sync with credentials necessary for it.

however there are a couple of things i,m unclear about and i tried to find them in the ceph documents but couldn't :

- the non trivial configuration represents a config file? if so where should i add it?
- the non trivial configuration has a default section, connections, acl_profiles and a profiles section. some of these information i don't know how to fill or even obtain, which are:
  1: the **acls** sub section in the default section
  2: the host_style parameter
  3: **acl_profiles** and **profiles** sections

if one could provide a more descriptive explanation than the docs of what these are i would be thankful
also if you have any references on where i could read up on these as well,
please comment so i can put in the time myself
my main problem is that i can't find any information on these to begin with and the documents are not very descriptive or have any useful examples